# What is the limit of this sequence? $x_n=\frac 13(x_{n-1} + \frac{6}{x_{n-1}})$, $x_0=2$

Tags: calculus, limits, recurrence-relations, recursion

$x_n=\frac 13(x_{n-1} + \frac{6}{x_{n-1}})$

Where $x_0 = 2$

I've calculated enough values to see that the limit of $x_n$ for $n$ to infinity is $\sqrt 3.$

But how do I prove this beside observation?

Comment: Hello :) If the limit $x$ exists, then your statement is correct, because we have $x=\frac 13(x+\frac 6x)$, which is equivalent to $x^2=3$. Because $x_n>0$ for all $n$, we get $x=\sqrt 3$.
But first, you have to prove, that the limit exists.

Comment: Hint: Let $f(x) = \frac13(x + \frac{6}{x})$. 1) show $x_n \ge x_c \stackrel{def}{=} \frac23\sqrt{6}$ for all $n$, 2) show $|f'(x)| \le |f'(x_c)| = \frac{5}{12}$ for $x \ge x_c$. 3) deduce $|x_{n+1}-\sqrt{3}| \le \frac{5}{12}|x_n - \sqrt{3}|$.

Comment: Something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969577/if-a-n2-frac13-lefta-n1-frac1a-n-right-then-lim-n-to).

Comment: MathJax Tip: Use the syntax ```$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)} $``` to yield $ \lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)} $

Answer (score 0):

First prove that it is bounded below by 1 and bounded above by 3 using induction and again by induction show that it is monotonic decreasing. It confirms the existence of limit and then it follows limit is $\sqrt3$.

Comment: Try to add a bit more detail on the derivation of the answer which will also help with your Math Stack Ex. career. Please see [How to write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP will not be able to prove that it is monotonic, because [it is not](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28n%29%3D1%2F3%28x%28n-1%29%2B6%2Fx%28n-1%29%29%2C+x%280%29%3D2).  @achillehui hint works for a proof, although he forgot to call it by its name: [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)

Comment: Yes you are  right.thank you for your suggestion.